# Unknown props - react and material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Currently I'm using react and material-ui and I've the following code in my component.

```
<Dialog
    title="Dialog With Actions"
    actions={actions}
    modal={false}
    open={this.state.open}
    onRequestClose={this.handleClose}>
      Are you sure that you want to proceed?
  </Dialog>
```

I've imported

```
import React from 'react';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
```

But I'm always getting the following error message

```
Warning: Unknown prop `onKeyboardFocus` on <button> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
Warning: Unknown prop `keyboardFocused` on <button> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
```

Comment: Probably has to do with the `FlatButton` and not the `Dialog`, right?

Comment: the"actions" are flatButtons     const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onClick={this.closeModal.bind(this)}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Submit"
        primary={true}
        onClick={this.promoteContent.bind(this)}
      />,
    ];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with material-ui that they've already [fixed](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4594). Wait for their `0.15.2` release or get their `master` branch now.

Answer (score 3):

Use [react-tap-event-plugin](https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin) to resolve this issue. After installing do this -

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

Comment: this worked for me

btw my material-ui ver > 1.5.2 (so the other answer didn't work).

Comment: be sure to have react and react-dom updated to **^15.4.0**, otherwise you'll get error ```Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/EventPluginHub'```  - https://github.com/prescottprue/generator-react-firebase/issues/27

Answer (score 2):

First, this is a warning and not an error message i.e. your code is still working. If you follow the [link](https://gist.github.com/jimfb/d99e0678e9da715ccf6454961ef04d1b) in the warning message, you can find out that:

> The unknown-prop warning will fire if you attempt to render a DOM
>   element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM
>   attribute/property. You should ensure that your DOM elements do not
>   have spurious props floating around.

There are more details and the possible reasons, but if I have to speculate you are passing all props to the button element.

Also interesting  is a comment bellow the note:

> For anyone who is curious/wondering why this new warning exists...
>
> > Historically, React has maintained a whitelist of all valid DOM
> >     attributes, and we would strip unrecognized attributes. This approach
> >     has a couple major downsides:
> >
> > - Performance: It means we must do a check for every prop on every DOM    element, to sanity check that the prop is valid, and strip the
> >       prop    if it is not legal. This is silly, because the majority of
> >       elements    are completely safe (no illegal attributes) and thus the
> >       checks are    just wasted CPU cycles.
> > - The old technique forced us to maintain a huge whitelist of all    possible DOM attributes. This is a pain to maintain, but more
> >       importantly, if we accidentally miss one or browser vendors add a new 
> >       one, it means that prop can't be used until we update our whitelist
> > - The old technique is less flexible because it is impossible to render    a non-standard attribute. While rendering non-standard
> >       attributes is    not recommended (you should use a data- attribute
> >       instead), sometimes    there are situations/frameworks that require
> >       it. It sucks that React    previously couldn't support it.
>
> As we move toward removing this whitelist, we need to give people an
>   opportunity to clean up their existing apps. This way, an upgrade
>   doesn't result in us dumping a ton of unexpected props into the DOM.

**EDIT**:
Most probably this is coming from the jsx of the library you are using ( material-ui ) Check if you are using the latest version or if you are, they should probably address it soon